# primes in integer valued polynomials.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, integer-valued-polynomials

For what finite degree integer-valued polynomials P does P contain a finite number of primes?

If I have a polynomial of degree n say $P(n)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}...a_1x+a_0$ is there a bound over the number of primes in the progretion for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: Do you mean "There are finitely many primes which divide $P(n)$ for some $n$" or do you mean "$P(n)$ takes prime values finitely often"?

Comment: i mean P(n) takes prime values infinitely often.

Comment: Since it is not known even whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^2+1$, little can be said with certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want polynomials $P(x)$ which take prime values infinitely often.

It is easy to see that for this to happen, $P(x)$ must satisfy the following conditions:

1. $a_n>0$ (For if $a_n<0$, $P(n)$ is eventually negative)
2. $P(x)$ irreducible  in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. (For if $P(x)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, say $P(x)=f(x)g(x)$, then for $P(x)$ to be prime, we require either $f(x)=\pm 1$ or $g(x)=\pm 1$, which have finitely many solutions.)
3. Write $P(x)$ as a integer combination of binomial coefficients $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{c_i\binom{x}{i}}$, then $\gcd(c_1, c_2, \ldots , c_n)=1$

This becomes [Bunyakovsky's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), which remains open. The degree $1$ case corresponds to Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progression, but not much has been proved for polynomials with higher degree.

Well... almost the same. Bunyakovsky's conjecture is concerning polynomials with integer coefficients, while you are looking at integer-valued polynomials. Shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: The integer $(-17)$ is prime! However, by symmetry it is enough to deal with only the $a_n > 0$ case.

Comment: @Hurkyl Well it really depends on what definition you use for "prime". Some people do restrict a prime integer to be positive, some don't. In any case, as you pointed out, it doesn't really matter here, for we can still restrict ourselves to $a_n>0$.